# Reading CloudSQL StackDriver logs through gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have logging enabled on my 2nd Generation CloudSQL instances in GCP - however I'm attempting to read these using the CLI and drawing a blank.

If I run `$ gcloud logging logs list` I can see the logs I want to read, example as follows:

```
projects/<project name>/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-slow.log
projects/<project name>/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err
```

The docs are confusing, but it looks like I should be able to read them if I run:

```
gcloud logging read "logName=projects/<project name>/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err" --limit 10 --format json
```

However this only returns a blank array as `[]`

I just want to read out the logs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the `gcloud logging read projects/<project name>/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql-slow.log` and `gcloud logging read projects/<project name>/logs/cloudsql.googleapis.com%2Fmysql.err`. As it is specified in [Quickstart using Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/quickstart-sdk#list-log-entries-using-sdk) documentation. Do not use the `"` in the command.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still getting a null return when I run it without the double quotes

Comment: Can you confirm with me if you are the owner of the project or at least your account has Cloud SQL admin privileges? Because your account needs to have proper role setup in IAM in order to load logs. Also can you please confirm with me, whether you can load any other logs from the logs list or the problem is only the the Cloud SQL?